# How do I send SMS from Windows CE 5.0?

Tags: vb.net, sms, compact-framework, windows-ce

I've been trying to send SMS from a Windows CE 5.0 device. I got some samples on the net, all using "sms.dll", but they don't seem to work. I'm starting to think they only work for 6.0. Is there an API I can use to send from 5.0?

Comment: I've got an SMS routine for my C# code, but I never was able to get it to work either. All I ever get is my custom exception saying "SMS Failed." I can post how I did it, if you want, but like I said - my version fails, too.

Comment: Please post it. Anything's worth looking at at this point. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say I understand what I did below, and like I said - I never got this to work for me.

That said, this is the class I used, from top to bottom, broken up with some explaining.

First, namespaces to include:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook.MessageInterception;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

I put this in it's own namespace so that it does not interfere with other stuff of mine, then declare some constants:

```
namespace MobileSMS {

  class SmsClass {

    private const Int32 FILE_DEVICE_HAL = 0x00000101;
    private const Int32 FILE_ANY_ACCESS = 0x0;
    private const Int32 METHOD_BUFFERED = 0x0;
    private static readonly Int32 IOCTL_HAL_GET_DEVICEID =
      ((FILE_DEVICE_HAL) << 16) | 
      ((FILE_ANY_ACCESS) << 14) |
      ((21) << 2) | (METHOD_BUFFERED);
    private const string NO_NAME = "[Unnamed]";
    private const string COREDLL = "coredll.dll";

    [DllImport(COREDLL)]
    private static extern bool KernelIoControl(Int32 IoControlCode, IntPtr InputBuffer, Int32 InputBufferSize, byte[] OutputBuffer, Int32 OutputBufferSize, ref Int32 BytesReturned);

  }

}
```

Those are all of my constants above.

```
    private string m_name;
    private MessageInterceptor m_sms;

    public SmsClass() {
      m_name = null;
      Exception error = null;
      try {
        m_sms = new MessageInterceptor(DeviceName, false);
        m_sms.InterceptionAction = InterceptionAction.NotifyAndDelete;
        m_sms.MessageCondition = new MessageCondition(MessageProperty.Body, MessagePropertyComparisonType.StartsWith, DeviceName);
        m_sms.MessageReceived += new MessageInterceptorEventHandler(Intercept_MessageReceived);
        m_sms.EnableApplicationLauncher(DeviceName);
      } catch (Exception err) {
        error = err; // just because there was an error doesn't mean it might not have been enabled.
      }
      if (!MessageInterceptor.IsApplicationLauncherEnabled(DeviceName)) {
        Console.WriteLine("Unable to load SMS Tool: " + error.Message);
      }
    }
```

Mine always fails there in the constructor. **Do not throw the error in a constructor (if you didn't know that), or the class acts weird.**

It is possible my class fails because of my definition of `IOCTL_HAL_GET_DEVICEID` - I can honestly say I didn't understand all of that. I just copied it down.

The `DeviceName` needs to be unique, so that one device can distinguish itself from the other when sending message (so I hear). Here is how I get a `DeviceName`: It searches the registry for an entry first, and if it can't find anything there, I use something I found on Microsoft to get a unique Serial Number (but it actually comes back looking more like a GUI).

```
    public string DeviceName {
      get {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(m_name)) {
          m_name = getName();
        }
        return m_name;
      }
      set {
        if (m_name != value) {
          m_name = value;
        }
      }
    }
```

This is my attempt to read my value from the Registry:

```
    private static string getName() {
      string name = null;
      using (var key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Ident", true)) {
        name = key.GetValue("Name", NO_NAME) as string;
      }
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) {
        name = getDeviceID();
      }
      return name;
    }
```

If that pulls nothing, I get a device ID using this code I found on MSDN:

```
    private static string getDeviceID() {
      // Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446562.aspx
      byte[] data = new byte[256];
      Int32 OutputBufferSize = data.Length;
      Int32 BytesReturned = 0;
      // Call KernelIoControl passing the previously defined IOCTL_HAL_GET_DEVICEID parameter
      // We don’t need to pass any input buffers to this call
      // so InputBuffer and InputBufferSize are set to their null values
      bool retVal = KernelIoControl(IOCTL_HAL_GET_DEVICEID, IntPtr.Zero, 0, data, OutputBufferSize, ref BytesReturned);
      // If the request failed, exit the method now
      if (retVal) {
        // Examine the OutputBuffer byte array to find the start of the 
        // Preset ID and Platform ID, as well as the size of the PlatformID. 
        // PresetIDOffset – The number of bytes the preset ID is offset from the beginning of the structure
        // PlatformIDOffset - The number of bytes the platform ID is offset from the beginning of the structure
        // PlatformIDSize - The number of bytes used to store the platform ID
        // Use BitConverter.ToInt32() to convert from byte[] to int
        Int32 PresetIDOffset = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 4);
        Int32 PlatformIDOffset = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0xc);
        Int32 PlatformIDSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0x10);

        // Convert the Preset ID segments into a string so they can be 
        // displayed easily.
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(String.Format("{0:X8}-{1:X4}-{2:X4}-{3:X4}-",
             BitConverter.ToInt32(data, PresetIDOffset),
             BitConverter.ToInt16(data, PresetIDOffset + 4),
             BitConverter.ToInt16(data, PresetIDOffset + 6),
             BitConverter.ToInt16(data, PresetIDOffset + 8)));
        // Break the Platform ID down into 2-digit hexadecimal numbers
        // and append them to the Preset ID. This will result in a 
        // string-formatted Device ID
        for (int i = PlatformIDOffset; i < PlatformIDOffset + PlatformIDSize; i++) {
          sb.Append(String.Format("{0:X2}", data[i]));
        }
        // return the Device ID string
        return sb.ToString();
      }
      return null;
    }
```

If an SMS message is ever received, it should be "caught" by this intercept. I think you're supposed to put something unique in the `command` so you can identify it as a message from one of your other devices and not something random trying to send something to anything listening. I never got that far, though, because my routine always fails in the constructor.

```
    private static void Intercept_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageInterceptorEventArgs e) {
      var newMessage = (SmsMessage)e.Message;
      if (newMessage != null) {
        Console.WriteLine("From: {0}", newMessage.From.Address);
        Console.WriteLine("Body: {0}", newMessage.Body);
        string[] command = newMessage.Body.Split(new char[] { '.' });
        string line = command[1];
        if (line == "helo") {
          /*do some Stuff*/
        }
      }
    }
```

Well, that's the whole thing! I hope it helps.